# Why am I getting an error like this even after linking all the required dependencies?

Tags: node.js, api, express

index.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const db = require("./models");

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
//Router
const userrouter = require("./routes/user");
app.use("./user", userrouter);

db.sequelize.sync().then(() => {
  app.listen(3001, () => {
    console.log("Hello I am server.");
  });
});
```

user.js

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const { Users } = require("../models");

router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  const noOfUsers = await Users.fetchAll();
  res.json(noOfUsers);
});
router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  const post = req.body;
  await Users.create(post);
  res.json(post);
});

module.exports = router;
```

users.js

```
module.exports = (sequelize,DataTypes)=>{
    const user = sequelize.define("Users",{
        name:{
            type:DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
        },
        description:{
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: true,
        },
        phone:{
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
        },
    });
    return user;
};
```

I have users.js in models folder. Why am I getting Cannot GET/ when I run the server? I am using node.js and I have also installed cors, mysql2, sequelize and express.

Comment: Try using `"../models/user"`

Comment: Also `app.use("./user", userrouter);` should be `app.use("/user", userrouter);` without the `.`

Answer (score 1):

If you look at your index.js file, you're using `app.use("./user", userrouter);` but it should be `app.use("/user", userrouter);`.